# TabItem style trigger doesn't update on application start

Tags: wpf, xaml

I attempted to create a simple style for a TabItem, by going to the Properties window and converting the template to a new resource, and wrapping it in a style (pretty standard stuff).

The goal is to animate the BorderBrush colour based on the `IsSelected` property. I've actually done this with relative ease, using the original generated code as a basis.

The problem: In the designer and when the application starts, all TabItems show as selected until I click on any tab which isn't the first one (index 0, since that's selected by default).

A screen recording demonstrating what happens:
https://i.gyazo.com/17e2f3c484029d4f5cd3021612b0f882.mp4

How can this be remedied? I have tried using the various trigger types and none seem to fix the problem.
The style code:

```html
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,0"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,1,0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Border x:Name="ElementBorder" Height="30" Width="Auto" Background="#FF1F1F1F" BorderBrush="#FF00FF96" BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" CornerRadius="2,2,0,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ContentPresenter TextBlock.Foreground="Silver"
                                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                        Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                        ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}"
                                        ContentSource="Header"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"
                                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                        RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                        VerticalAlignment="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                                
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                
                        <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ElementBorder"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                        To="#FF00FF96"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                                
                        <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ElementBorder"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                        To="#FF1F1F1F"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                                
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you set your default BorderBrush to be the selected color. Change it to be the unselected color like so:

```
<Border x:Name="ElementBorder"
    Width="Auto"
    Height="30"
    Background="#FF1F1F1F"
    BorderBrush="#FF1F1F1F"
    BorderThickness="0,0,0,2"
    CornerRadius="2,2,0,0"
    SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
```

Also, you can simplify your trigger:

```
<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
    <Trigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation
                    Storyboard.TargetName="ElementBorder"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                    To="#FF00FF96"
                    Duration="0:0:0.1" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </Trigger.EnterActions>
    <Trigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation
                    Storyboard.TargetName="ElementBorder"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                    To="#FF1F1F1F"
                    Duration="0:0:0.1" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </Trigger.ExitActions>
</Trigger>
```

Comment: Ah yes, thank you so much, setting the border's default colour as the selected colour was an oversight on my part. I thought the triggers were playing up. As for simplifying the trigger, yes, what you've shown is how I originally had it on the first attempt. Thank you!